# ArcPy preventing copying files using Transfer Files tool

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, copy

I am using ArcPy to calculate some areas in polygons.

At the end of my code, I want to copy my final files over to a DropBox folder using the [Transfer Files](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/transfer-files.htm) tool. The following code moves the files across:

```
... do stuff 
#This moves all files that start with deapsea_shares to dropbox
files = os.listdir(in_dir_temp)
for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("deepsea_shares")):
        arcpy.TransferFiles(f, in_dir)

print("Done!")
```

However when running the code, it returns error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'deepsea_shares.cpg'

However, when I run the above code in a separate python file, it copies them across normally with no error . This makes me think that ArcPy is somehow blocking the moving of these files through some lock mechanism because the file is clearly in the directory.

I also noticed that the deapsea_shares.shp file can be moved across (in the original code), but not the .cpg file, I have not explicitly tested other files yet.

Do you have any insight into this problem?

Edit: I made a mistake in original question, I was atually using this block of code:

```
print("Moving file to dropbox...")

sys.exit()
#This moves all files that start with deapsea_shares to dropbox
files = os.listdir(in_dir_temp)
for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("deepsea_shares")):
        print(f)
        shutil.move(f, in_dir)
```

This is what returned the error.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcMap but are you using that or ArcGIS Pro with ArcPy?

Comment: `f` is a file without path, try: `arcpy.TransferFiles(os.path.join(in_dir_temp,f), in_dir)`

Comment: @PolyGeo ArcPy .

Comment: @BERA It did not work, it said module not found.

Comment: @BERA is onto something as the tool does not support Workspace. Thus you need to be explicit in your inputs: either a fully qualified folder or a fully qualified file path. You need to `import os` at the start to use that module.

Comment: Your revised code appears to have no GIS component and I think would be better researched at [so] as a pure Python question.

Answer (score 2):

`f` is a filename without path so TransferFiles wont find it.

try:

```
arcpy.TransferFiles(os.path.join(in_dir_temp,f), in_dir)
```

os.path.join will combine your path with the filename.

Example:

```
import os

folder = '/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/'

for f in os.listdir(folder):
    print(f)

#ok_bs_riks_sample2.cpg
#rutor.shx
#...

for f in os.listdir(folder):
    print(os.path.join(folder,f))

#/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/ok_bs_riks_sample2.cpg
#/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/rutor.shx
#...
```